# Displaying Json variables in labels C#

Tags: c#, json, serialization, label

I have this class:

```
public class Userinfo
{

    public Userinfo()
    {

    }
    public static async Task<List<Information>> Login(string Username, string Password)
    {
        string str = "https://somesite.com/log.php";
        string[] cID = new string[] { "act=qwjFpPXuGexZBHDJEreZrAUH&CID=", "&username=", Username, "&password=", Password };
        string str1 = string.Concat(cID);

        using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
        {
            webClient.Proxy = null;
            webClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            string str2 = webClient.UploadString(str, str1)
            var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Information>>(str2);
            return result;
        }
     }
  }
```

Which returns this JSON

```
[{"username":"fakeuser","email":"fakeemail@outlook.com","plan":"1","activationdate":"18\/12\/20","terminationdate":"18\/01\/21"}]
```

What I want to do is set in another form the data inside the `result` variable in labels so they can display the actual content. The problem is that if I debug the code the variable seems to be empty. If I make a break and hover the mouse over the variable it doesn't show anything and it doesn't even appear on the variable list. So, what am I doing wrong?

This is the code I have in the form where I have the labels:

```
private async void Filldata()
    {
        var result = await Userinfo.Login("username", "password");
        
        label11.Text = result.Select(x => x.username).FirstOrDefault();
        label18.Text = result.Select(x => x.email).FirstOrDefault();
        label19.Text = result.Select(x => x.plan).FirstOrDefault();
        label20.Text = result.Select(x => x.activationdate).FirstOrDefault();
        label21.Text = result.Select(x => x.terminationdate).FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

And here is my class where I deserialize the JSON:

```
public class Information
{
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string plan { get; set; }
    public string activationdate { get; set; }
    public string terminationdate { get; set; }

}
```

I think it's worth mentioning that the classes are separate. Userinfo and Information are their own classes.

What am I missing and how can I solve this?

Posted again because I haven't been able to solve this.

Comment: When you debug and hover on str2, is there any value?

Comment: No, but if instead I do `public static async Task Login(string Username, string Password)` then everything is fine

Comment: Are you debugging under release config or debug config

Comment: so when you make it `Task Login`, you still call it like this `string str2 = webClient.UploadString(str, str1)
            var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Information>>(str2);` ?

Comment: and you get response?

Comment: Yes, but obviously without the `return result;` and I do get response from str2 normally. But with `public static async Task<List<Information>> Login(string Username, string Password)` i get nothing

Comment: @Jawad I set a breakpoint and run the app.

Comment: Is there a reason Filldata is async void? Is it an event handler?

Comment: There is a place to set the config to either release or debug. Make sure it is set to debug so you can see the values of the variables. In release config, most variables are optimized away

Comment: Its already set to debug. Is my code missing something? Would you suggest another approach? Like I said my goal is to set the content of the variable in the labels in another form

Comment: Where's the async part in `Userinfo.Login()`? There's none. At least, call and await [UploadStringTaskAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.uploadstringtaskasync). `Filldata()` is `async void`. You also need to change that. For now, there's nothing *async* here.

Comment: Should it be `private async Task Filldata()` ? If you could suggest the changes in code would be much better for me to undestand and also that way I could try and report back